# What is the syntax for sending Jabber/Gtalk notifications in Monit

Tags: xmpp, monit

I noticed in the release log (http://mmonit.com/wiki/MMonit/Release2-1) Monit supports Jabber/GTalk messages but I can't find the proper syntax in any of the documentation. I'm trying to send out an alert via gTalk when a host goes down.

Answer (score 3):

M/Monit (the Monit management server) can send XMPP messages. The monit daemon can only send email on its own.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a custom command to send the notifications?

Comment: @thomas.mc.work, one way would be to set the recipient to a local address and add a command in /etc/aliases, such as: alerts: "|sendalert"